# Get numbers next and after a certain number with dynamic max results with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I have a pagination which renders some pages. I have a setting where the user can define how many pages are to be displayed as numbers in the pagination nav. The first and last number are always visible. Now if the user wants to have 3 numbers on the nav and assuming that i am now in the page 7, then it should look like this:

```
1 ... 6 7 8 ... 12
```

If the user wants four items then it should look like that:

```
1 ... 6 7 8 9 ... 12
```

Up until now i have the following which gives me 3 before and after the current page

```
$maxLinks = 3;
$currentPageNumber = 7;


$pages = [];
$pages[] = 1;
for($i = max(2, $currentPageNumber - $maxLinks); $i <= min($currentPageNumber + $maxLinks, 12 - 1); $i++) {
       $pages[] = $i;
  }
 $pages[] = 12;
foreach ($pages as $key => $page) {
   $newPage = '...';
   if (($key === 0) && $pages[1] !== $page + 1) {
      array_splice( $pages, 1, 0, $newPage );
   }
   $itemBeforeLast = count($pages)-2;
   if (is_numeric($pages[$itemBeforeLast]) && ($key === $itemBeforeLast) && $pages[$itemBeforeLast + 1] !== $pages[$itemBeforeLast] + 1) {
      array_splice( $pages, $itemBeforeLast +1, 0, $newPage );
   }
}
```

This gives me back the following:

[image]

But i only want to get 3 or 4 numbers between the dots (this changes based on the value that the user gives in the settings (`$maxLinks` variable))

Any help is deeply appreciated

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you add them to both sides, you need to divide by 2. Also, remove 1 to account for the current page. Then you just need to account for the possibility of having a non-even number of links to the left&right by rounding (down for the left, up for the right).

And end up with:

```
for($i = max(2, $currentPageNumber - floor(($maxLinks-1)/2)); 
    $i <= min($currentPageNumber + ceil(($maxLinks-1)/2), 12 - 1); $i++)
```

Comment: I was halfway through a similar answer. I'd just like to mention you could switch the `floor` and `ceil` positions if you want to distribute an even number of pages differently (if `floor` is first, then it will produce something like `... 6, 7, 8, 9 ...` and `ceil` first would produce something like `... 5, 6, 7, 8 ...` - assuming 7 as the current page in both cases).

Comment: Adding to the answer, while coding it yourself like this if ofc fine, you could also check how bigger frameworks implement pagination (and the slider rendering), to get the idea of an alternative and arguably cleaner approach: https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Pagination